# Cannot understand this Inline block behaviour?

Tags: html, css

Why is the Relative Sibling div not in the same line as Sibling div.
But Adding position: relative and top: 50px to the relative class moves the Relative Sibling to the same line as Sibling.
If I remove the br tag the Parent moves down to the same line as Sibling line but Relative sibling is still not in the same line.

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14pt;
    }
    .bordered {
      border: 2px solid #2e3d49;
    }
    .parent {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #dbe2e8;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    .light-olive {
      background-color: #DFDFD1;
    }
    .relative {
      /* position: relative; */
      top: 50px;
    }
    .sibling {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #15C26B;
      width: 150px;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .child {
      background-color: #ffae0c;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Relative Flow Quiz</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <meta name="udacity-grader" content="tests.json">

</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">Parent<br>
    <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
    <div class="sibling relative bordered">Relative Sibling
      <div class="child bordered">Child</div>
      <div class="child bordered">Child</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
  </div>
  <span class="light-olive">
    Sibling to the parent
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `vertical-align:top;` on  `.sibling`

```
.sibling {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #15C26B;
      width: 150px;
      vertical-align:top;
      height: 100px;
    }
```

```css
 * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14pt;
    }
    .bordered {
      border: 2px solid #2e3d49;
    }
    .parent {
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #dbe2e8;
      padding: 8px;
    }
    .light-olive {
      background-color: #DFDFD1;
    }
    .relative {
      /* position: relative; */
      top: 50px;
    }
    .sibling {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #15C26B;
      width: 150px;
      vertical-align:top;
      height: 100px;
    }
    .child {
      background-color: #ffae0c;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">Parent<br>
    <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
    <div class="sibling relative bordered">Relative Sibling
      <div class="child bordered">Child</div>
      <div class="child bordered">Child</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
  </div>
  <span class="light-olive">
    Sibling to the parent
  </span>
```

Comment: Thnx! It worked but Can you tell the reason why it was happening?